# why i can not navigate to another screen the text button is working but i can't navigate

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

why i can not navigate to another screen the text button is working but i can't navigate

```
TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Status()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'STATUS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: show your error and show the full pages code... maybe you called another function or widget instead of your page